# Getting the first parent of a hierarchical term

Tags: categories

How get `avô` this hierarqui category:

```
avô
-mae
--filho
```

It always give me the last child :

```
<?php 

    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); 

    echo $single_cat->slug;

?>
```

Result: `filho`

Must obtain the category `avô`

**UPDATE:**

`$product_cats` return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 16
            [name] => Display
            [slug] => filho
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 16
            [taxonomy] => product_cat
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 7
            [count] => 2
            [filter] => raw
        )

)
```

Comment: What does $product_cats return exactly?

Comment: @vancoder, Updated my question ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in a Single Post you'll need to first get the categories then use [`get_ancestors()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) to display the hierarchy.

```
$product_cats   = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

if( ! empty( $product_cats ) ) {

    $single_cat     = array_shift( $product_cats );

    $product_ancs   = get_ancestors( $single_cat->term_id, 'product_cat' );

    if( ! empty( $product_ancs ) ) {

        $top_level_cat  = array_shift( array_reverse( $product_ancs ) );

        $single_cat     = get_term( $top_level_cat, 'product_cat' );
    }

    echo $single_cat->slug;
}
```

The above example runs some error checking if there are no categories checked or if the term attached has no parents. First we get all the Post Terms and use only 1 as the basis to get all its ancestors. If it has a parent or grandparent, it will be at the end of our `$product_ancs` array. Let's look at the [example given in The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term#Examples):

- Books (6)

  - Fiction (23)

    - Mystery (208)

`<?php get_ancestors( 208, 'category' ); ?>` Returns the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 23
    [1] => 6
)
```

With the top level being at the end of the array which is way we take advantage of [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).

---

A secondary method would be to use a loop and go through each term 1 by 1 until you reach the top. Every parent shouldn't have a parent ( `$top_term->parent` will be 0 -> false -> empty ) so we can look for that in our loop:

```
 $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

 $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats );

 if( ! empty( $product_cats ) ) {

        $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats );

        $top_term = $single_cat;

        if( $top_term->parent > 0 ) {

            while( $top_term->parent > 0 ) {

                $top_term = get_term( $top_term->parent, 'product_cat' );

            }

        } else {

           $attr = 'no_parent';

        }

        $attr = $top_term->slug;

    } else {

        $attr = 'empty_categories';

    }
```

Once the `while` loop returns false ( reaches a parent of 0 ) we know we've hit the top of our hierarchy.

Comment: @Lollipop I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Lollipop Gotta be more descriptive than that, do you have debugging enabled? What does `$product_ancs` print out? Are you certain every category has a parent? If `$product_ancs` returns false then that means there are no parents and `$single_cat` gets assigned to the first term in the post.

Comment: @Lollipop Is this still the same example as in your question? The ones where `$product_ancs` returns an empty array, what is `$single_cat->parent` value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21576/discussion-between-howdy-mcgee-and-lollipop).